# Redirect on Listview row click

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, click, row

I have a `Listview` and one of the columns is called `id_Number`.
Is it possible to redirect to another page, if user clicks on one of the rows?
For example if `id_Number` is 4, than page should be redirected to `~/Page.aspx?id=4`.

Code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="id_Number" >
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>               
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="font-family: Arial; color: #FFFFFF" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#219DD0';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#252526';">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id_Number") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="TextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="Table2" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="">
                            <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                                Name</th>
                            <th id="Th2" runat="server">
                                Text</th>
                            <th id="Th3" runat="server">
                                Date</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate> 
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: To get help, you should edit your question and add the relevant code and markup of your list view. Yes it's possible, and quite simple.. You can use an HTML link or pure JavaScript to accomplish this, which you'd add to the list view rows, columns, item template, etc. However it's hard to be specific without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an HTML link or a JavaScript into the `ItemTemplate` of your `ListView` pretty easily:

The "columns" are just HTML columns; in the ItemTemplate, you have access to all of your data, including id_number, so you can use it anywhere in the HTML, not just inside a column.

Since you wan the whole row to be clickable, I'd use a JavaScript function on the `onClick` event of the HTML table row `<TR>` element. You already have 2 events (onMouseOver, onMouseOut), with JavaScript in them, so this would just be one more...

A JavaScript redirect utilizes `window.location.href` which will redirect in the same window, assuming that's what you want (as opposed to a new window, etc.):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="font-family: Arial; color: #FFFFFF" 
        onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#219DD0';" 
        onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#252526';"
        onClick="window.location.href = 'some/path/Page.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id_Number") %>';"
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id_Number") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="TextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

One thing to note is for the path of Page.aspx, you have to use a relative path.

```
~/page.aspx?id=
```

Is a .net path that gets compiled into the full relative path to that page.
However, bacause your ItemTemplate contains HTML, you'd need the full (relative) path to Page.aspx in there.

So instead it should be (just an example):

```
/some/path/page.aspx?id=   <-- page.aspx lives on http://www.yoursite.com/some/path/page.aspx
/page.aspx?id=             <-- page.aspx lives on root, http://www.yoursite.com/page.aspx
```

Alternately you can use

```
onClick="window.location.href = '<% System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Page.Aspx?ID=" + Eval("id_number")); %>';"
```